# web3.eth.accounts.wallet.add(account) not working

Tags: go-ethereum

I need help with adding a new wallet to a web3 instance.
e.g.:

```
web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(connectionString));
const account = await web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount('0x'+pvKey);
await web3.eth.accounts.wallet.add(account);
console.log(await web3.eth.getAccounts()); // return []..
```

as you can see, there is no account added to the web3.eth.accounts instance.
I need to see the new address added to the accounts list.

web3@1.0.0-beta.36.
pow blockchain network.
Node v8.11.4

any clue?

Answer (score 0):

You are adding an account to the [wallet](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-accounts.html#wallet), which is an in-memory object containing multiple accounts (not to the [accounts](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-accounts.html#web3-eth-accounts), which is an object containing functions for generating Ethereum accounts).

Change this:

```
console.log(await web3.eth.getAccounts());
```

To this:

```
console.log(web3.eth.accounts.wallet);
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, But, when I'm trying to run smart contracts function it is saying to me invalid sender: Returned error: invalid sender                                      [e.g. : await tokenContractInstance.methods.issue(wallet,amount).send({from:webServiceWallet,gas:'4000000'}).catch(ex=> console.log('error1:', ex));]

Comment: @NicholasBrodoviz: What has that got to do with any of the details that you posted in your question, or with any of the details that I wrote in my answer?????

Comment: how I can add a new account to the web3 object to run contract functions? (from specific sender)

Comment: @NicholasBrodoviz: If this is a new question, then please post it in a separate post.

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/67658/how-i-can-add-a-new-account-to-the-web3-object-to-run-contract-functions-from

Comment: @Nicholas Brodoviz did you get the answer for the above question `how-i-can-add-a-new-account-to-the-web3-object-to-run-contract-functions-from` ?